# Getting callback is undefined error in firebug console while creating a datasource using kendo ui

Tags: web-services, kendo-ui

My webservice generates jsonp response same as http://demos.kendoui.com/service/products.

When i try to create datasource for my webservice i am getting callback is not defined error in firebug console.

Webservice response.

callback([{"category":null,"productName":"Puma","productId":1,"quantity":0,"price":3000.0,"categoryId":1,"description":"ok"}])

But when i use kendo ui webservice (http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Products) i am getting a valid datasource.

Code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            //url: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/products",
                            url: "http://localhost:8080/mobile-services/rest/categories/1/products.json",
                            dataType: "jsonp"
                        }
                    },
                    pageSize: 12
                });

            $("#pager").kendoPager({
                dataSource: dataSource
            });

            $("#listView").kendoListView({
                dataSource: dataSource,
                template: kendo.template($("#template").html())
            });
        });
```

please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the function name is not `callback` 
 callback is just the key and the function itself maybe called sth like `jQuery17101014779508113`
 Can you look at what your datasource is sending to the server during the read operation? (Chrome / Firebug Network Tab) 
 I'm taking the $_REQUEST['callback'] variable (with a PHP-Script) and just returning it as the padding. Since you're just using a static .json file and the callback function name will be changed on each request (to prevent caching), you won't ever have the correct function name. 
So: I suggest you use JSON instead of P or you dynamically return the same callback you're receiving. 
Cheers....

Answer (score 0):

You have specified JSONP as `dataType` and you are requesting a JSON file. JSONP and JSON are not the same. Try using `dataType: "json"`.